# Check if a new field was added in a specific document like documentChanges for a collection in Firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I use this code for load comments in a table view:

```
func observePostComments(postId: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("post-comments").document(postId).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, err) in

        if snapshot!.exists {
            for key in (snapshot?.data()!.keys)! {
                completion(key)
        }
        } else {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

It works like it should, but every time a user creates a new comment, all comments are added again. I know how it works for a collection with:

```
querySnapshot?.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
        if (diff.type == .added) { ....
```

But I can not figure out how to implement that functionality on a document / field level. If I want to do the same on a document level, I receive 
*Value of type 'DocumentSnapshot?' has no member 'documentChanges'*.

How can I track changes on a specific document level, when a new Key-Value pair was added to a document?

Comment: The new key's added to your document is known key's or will be user generated key's. If you know the keys you can check it in documents changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore's change detection only works on complete documents. If you need to know what changed *inside* a document, you will have to detect this in your own code, for example by comparing the previous `DocumentSnapshot` with the new one.

The exact way to do this depends a bit on what data you store, but there are two broad approaches:

1. You take something that is unique about each comment, and check if that's already present in your UI. This can for example be the ID of each comment, but anything else that's unique works too.
2. You store a timestamp for each comment, and keep track of the most recent timestamp you've already processed. Then in an update, you skip all comments up until that timestamp.

Another approach would be to clear the UI before adding the same comments to it. So something like:

```
db.collection("post-comments").document(postId).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, err) in

if snapshot!.exists {
    clearCommentsFromUI() // this is a function you will have to implement
    for key in (snapshot?.data()!.keys)! {
        completion(key)
}
```